# Apply Width To DIV (pagination)

Tags: jquery, css, width, center

I currently have a pagination module that can't be done in a ul/li. it's just a surrounding div w/ a bunch of anchors inside.

```
<div class="pagination">
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
</div>
```

Each  has padding to make the width/height since the numbers can go from single digit to triple digit (1-1##). I need to center the pagination, but without a width I can't do it. The width is always changing depending on the numbers in the pagination. How can I apply the width of all the  to the containing  w/ class 'pagination'?

```
var pagWidth = $('.pagination').width();
$('.pagination').css('width',pagWidth);
```

I know this is incorrect, as it will apply the width of the  which will calculate 100% of whatever width the div is in. Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with css. To centre your `div` use the following :

```
.pagination
{
   margin:0px auto;
}
```

or use it's equivalent in javascript.

To calculate the width of all the children.

```
var totalWidth = 0;

$("div.pagination").children().each(function() {
   totalWidth = totalWidth + $(this).width();
});

$('.pagination').css('width',totalWidth);
```

Comment: without a width, the margin auto for left/right doesn't do anything since the automatic width is 100% of the container/page it's in. thats why a width needs to be set and then it'll center with '0 auto'

Comment: @user2029729 added some code to calculate the children widths to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work in your situation to simply add width: 100%; to the pagination div (since the width is always changing)?

```
.pagination {
   margin:0px auto;
   width: 100%;
}
```